# couldn't store event in android Calender

Tags: android, calendar

hey i'm trying to add a calender event from my app but it didn't working at all i cant see my event in the calender app neither i didn't get the Reminder this is my code

```
public class CalendarSync {
    Context context;

    public CalendarSync(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void pushAppointmentsToCalender(Activity curActivity, int eID,
            String title, String addInfo, String place, int status,
            long startDate, long endDate, boolean needReminder,
            boolean needOnTimeReminder) {

        try {
            String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
            ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

            eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1);
            eventValues.put("title", title);
            eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
            eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);

            eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
            eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);
            eventValues.put("eventTimezone", getTimeZone());

            eventValues.put("eventStatus", status);
            eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1);

            Uri eventUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext()
                    .getContentResolver()
                    .insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
            long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
            long reminderId = 0;

            try {
                saveCalenderId(String.valueOf(eID) + "_e", eventID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (needReminder) {
                String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";



                ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

                reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
                reminderValues.put("minutes", 120);
                reminderValues.put("method", 1);
                Uri reminderUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext()
                        .getContentResolver()
                        .insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);

                reminderId = Long.parseLong(reminderUri.getLastPathSegment());
                saveCalenderId(String.valueOf(eID) + "_r", reminderId);
            }

            if (needOnTimeReminder) {
                String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

                ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

                reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
                reminderValues.put("minutes", 0);
                reminderValues.put("method", 0);
                Uri reminderUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext()
                        .getContentResolver()
                        .insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);

                reminderId = Long.parseLong(reminderUri.getLastPathSegment());
                saveCalenderId(String.valueOf(eID) + "_r", reminderId);
            }

            Log.e("save event", String.valueOf(eID) + "_e" + "-" + eventID);
            Log.e("save reminder", String.valueOf(eID) + "_r" + "-"
                    + reminderId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getTimeZone() {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        return tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
    }

    private void saveCalenderId(String eventIdKey, long eventIdValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "Lemeno", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putLong(eventIdKey, eventIdValue);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

and here how i call it

```
    CalendarSync cs = new CalendarSync(ViewEventActivity.this);
                cs.pushAppointmentsToCalender(
                        (Activity) ViewEventActivity.this, eventVO
                                .getEventId(), eventVO.getEventName(),
                        "Lemeno Event", eventVO.getLocationName(), 1,
                        System.currentTimeMillis(), new Timestamp(eventVO
                                .getEventDate().getTime()).getTime(), true,
                        false);
```

any help please?